# Change one django form field value relative to another

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Let say I have two fields in a django form `country` and `state`.I want the values of `state` to relatively change with the values of `country`.i.e. I want the `state` field to list out the states of the `country` that user has selected. Also the `state` field should be empty during form initiation.I know that this can be done using java script and other scripts.But,I would like to know if there are any conventional methods exists in django to do the same.???

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create a model for Country and State.

State model should have a foreign key linking to Country. This means many states can be related to one country. Then, populate the tables with all countries and states you want.

In your form, you can override the '**init**' method with custom behavior. So, if you have declared a field 'state' then you can do something like `self.fields['state'].choices = State.object.filter(country_id=some_country_id)`. This assumes you have some_country_id already and you can pass this through as a kwarg during instantiation.